# Calculating this limit relating to multiple integral

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let $g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and satisfy $g(x,y)\geqq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ and $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} g(x,y)dxdy=1.$

Define $g_t (x,y):=\dfrac{g\left(\frac{x}{t}, \frac{y}{t}\right)}{t^2}$ for $t>0.$

Then,

(i) Calculate $\iint_\mathbb {R^2} g_t (x,y) dx dy$.

(ii) Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to + 0} \iint_{D} g_t(x,y) dxdy$, where $D=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2 \geqq 1\}$.

I did (i) and I found $\iint_\mathbb {R^2} g_t (x,y) dx dy=1.$

I haven't done (ii) yet.

---

Here is what I considered.

I think I can use (i).

$1=\int_{\mathbb R^2} g_t(x,y) dxdy=\int_{x^2+y^2 <1} g_t (x,y) dxdy+ \int_{D} g_t (x,y) dxdy$, thus $\int_{D} g_t (x,y) dxdy
=1-\int_{x^2+y^2 <1} g_t (x,y) dxdy.$

If I use polar coordinates,

\begin{align}
\int_{x^2+y^2 <1} g_t (x,y) dxdy
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 g_t (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta) r dr d\theta \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{r}{t^2} g\left(\frac{r \cos \theta}{t}, \frac{r \sin \theta}{t}\right)   dr d\theta \\
\end{align}

And I want to calculate $\lim_{t \to +0}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{r}{t^2} g\left(\frac{r \cos \theta}{t}, \frac{r \sin \theta}{t}\right)   dr d\theta$ but calculating this limit seems not to be easy.

I also tried with Taylor expansion of $g$ (at $(0,0)$) and this also seems not to work.

So, I'm having difficulty in calculating (ii). I'd like you to give me any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As regards (ii), after letting $X=x/t$ and $Y=y/t$,
\begin{align}
\int_{x^2+y^2<1} g_t (x,y) dxdy&=\int_{x^2+y^2 <1}\dfrac{g\left(\frac{x}{t}, \frac{y}{t}\right)}{t^2} dxdy=\int_{X^2+Y^2 <1/t^2}\dfrac{g\left(X, Y\right)}{t^2} t^2dXdY\\
&=\int_{X^2+Y^2 <1/t^2}g\left(X, Y\right)dXdY.
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0^+}\int_{x^2+y^2<1} g_t (x,y) dxdy&=
\lim_{t \to 0^+}\int_{X^2+Y^2 <1/t^2}g\left(X, Y\right)dXdY\\
&=\lim_{R \to +\infty}\int_{X^2+Y^2 <R^2}g\left(X, Y\right)dXdY=
\iint_{\mathbb R^2} g(X,Y)dXdY=1
\end{align}
and by (i) we may conclude that
$$\lim_{t \to 0^+}\int_{D} g_t (x,y) dxdy=1-\lim_{t \to 0^+}\int_{x^2+y^2 <1} g_t (x,y) dxdy=0.$$

Comment: What theorem justifies $ \int_{X^2+Y^2< R^2}\to \int_{X^2+Y^2<\infty}$ as $R \to \infty$ ? @Robert_Z

Comment: By definition of multivariable improper integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Improper_integrals_over_arbitrary_domains